# click button to toggle show one component and hide another component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, listview, gridview

I have two separate button like grid and list button:

```
<button 
     onClick={() => setClassName('jsGridView')}
     title="Grid View"
 >
     <IoGrid className="active" size="25"/>
</button>  

<button 
     onClick={() => setClassName('jsListView')}
     title="List View"
   >
    <BiAlignLeft size="25"/>
</button>

const [cName, setClassName] = useState('jsGridView');
```

So when i click Grid view button it will show this component:

```
<GridCard className={cName}/>
```

and when i click list view button it will show

```
<ListCard className={cName}/>
```

with this mentioned className..

class is changed button but show hide component is not working.

Comment: Where are `GridCard` and `ListCard` in the code?

Comment: this two are my separate components i just show this component when button is clicked i mean className is matched and another will be hide

Comment: instead of hiding using classname you can conditionally render components. example `isGridView ? <GridCard />  : <ListCard >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display different components depending on the value of `cName`.

```
<div className="row mt-4 book-div">
   <div className={cName}>   
   { cName === 'jsGridView' ? <BooksGridCard/> : <BooksListCard/> } 
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check updated answer.